# Why is it that my media queries not working in my code?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm fairly new to html css and started building a landing page that I got from the front end mentor challenges shown below. So it far it looks good on desktop.

[Coming soon landing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSIAn.png)

However, I'm having trouble making it responsive. I tried to change the grid template columns to rows but it just didn't work. Why is this?

Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="top-img">
        <div class="container"> 
    <img src="./images/logo.svg" class="navbar-brand" alt="#">
</div>
</nav>

<!-- Section hero-->
<section id="hero">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="hero-text">
            <h1>We're<span> Coming Soon</span></h1>
            <p>Hello fellow shoppers! We're currently building our new fashion store. Add your email below to stay up-to-date with announcements and or launch deals.</p>
            <div class="icons">
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hero-img">
            <img src="./images/hero-desktop.jpg" alt="#">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/732aafddc7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300,400,600&display=swap');  

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {

    /* primary */
    --desaturated-color: hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
    --soft-red: hsl(0, 93%, 68%);
    /*neutral*/
    --dark-red: hsl(0, 6%, 24%);
    /* font size - body: 16px */
    --body-font: 16px;

}

.container {
    /*max-width: 1200px;*/
    padding: 2rem 3rem;
}



#hero {
    background: url(../images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg) no-repeat center center/cover;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

.navbar-brand {
    padding-left: 3rem;
}

.hero-text {
    width: 60%;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    margin-top: 10rem;
    margin-left: 6rem;
}

.hero-text h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--desaturated-color);
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.hero-text p {
      font-size: var(--body-font);
      color: var(--desaturated-color);
     margin-bottom: 2rem;
     line-height: 2;
}
.hero-text span {
    color: var(--dark-red);
    font-weight: 600;
}

.top-img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.hero-img img {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100vh;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr;

}

input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid var(--desaturated-color);
    border-color: var(--desaturated-color);
}

::placeholder {
    color: var(--desaturated-color);
}

.icons {
    position: relative;
}

.icons i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    right: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,  hsl(0, 80%, 86%),  hsl(0, 74%, 74%));
    padding: 0.5rem 3rem;
     height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 25px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .grid {
        grid-template-rows: 3fr 2fr; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're specifying `grid-template-columns` outside of your media query; and thus, it is being applied to all screen sizes. To fix, you simply need to specify in your media query that you don't want your content to be displayed in columns - and then your current `grid-template-rows` element will work correctly.

See below:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .grid {
        grid-template-columns: none; /* ADD THIS */
        grid-template-rows: 3fr 2fr; 
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7em5bka/)

Answer (score 0):

At the media query add this row under grid-template-rows:

grid-template-columns: none;

You have to overwrite the specified columns, or it will be applied to the responsive version too.

Answer (score 0):

Please put grid-template-columns: none;

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
 .grid {
    grid-template-rows: 3fr 2fr; 
    grid-template-columns: none; 
 }
}
```

Or another way user display: block; for a mobile version.

```
 @media (max-width: 768px) {
 .grid {
    display: block;
 }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

in responisve first reset grid column then apply row it will work